# GameCenter in Swift - Sending and Receiving Data

Tags: swift, game-center

I'm both new to swift and GameCenter. I'm creating a small multiplayer game that requires me to transfer data between players. I'm unsure on how to do this since almost everything I find is in Objective-C and I'm not fully comfortable with either language to be able to translate code from one to another.

The datatype that I want to be able to send to another player and have them receive it, is an (x,y) coordinate declared in a structure as so...

```
struct Point: 
{
    var x:Int = 0;
    var y:Int = 0;
}
```

In the iOS Developer Library there is a GameCenter programming guide that contains the following code...

```
- (void) sendPosition
{
    NSError *error;
    PositionPacket msg;
    msg.messageKind = PositionMessage;
    msg.x = currentPosition.x;
    msg.y = currentPosition.y;
    NSData *packet = [NSData dataWithBytes:&msg length:sizeof(PositionPacket)];
    [match sendDataToAllPlayers: packet withDataMode: GKMatchSendDataUnreliable error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
}

- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID
{
    Packet *p = (Packet*)[data bytes];
    if (p.messageKind == PositionMessage)
    {
        // Handle a position message.
    }
}
```

From what I understand the above code seems to be doing exactly what I want my project to do.

**QUESTIONS**
- **How do I transfer the above code into swift and make it work with my Point structure?**
- **The GC programming guide mentions about message formatting and using           enumerations for example, in order to differentiate between different messages. Do I need to make such changes to my structure even though I will always be sending the same type of message?**